# implement "done" button in UIToolBar to close UIDatePicker and ToolBar

Tags: swift, button, datepicker, toolbar

I want to close my uidatepicker and my toolbar by pressing a "done"-button in my toolbar.

I am using a label instead of a textfield so the common solutions don't work.

I have tried:

```
@IBAction func ButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("hallo")

    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.backgroundColor = .white
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
    //picker.sizeToFit()


    var datumComponents = DateComponents()
    datumComponents.year = 2019
    datumComponents.month = 6
    datumComponents.day = 1
    let meinStartKalender = Calendar.current
    let StartDatum = meinStartKalender.date(from: datumComponents)

    picker.minimumDate = StartDatum
    picker.maximumDate = Date()
    let pickerSize1 = myView.bounds.width 
    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dueDateChanged(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)  
    picker.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y: self.view.frame.height - 300 , width: pickerSize1, height: 200)
    self.view.addSubview(picker)



    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.backgroundColor = .red
    toolBar.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y: self.view.frame.height - 340 , width: pickerSize1, height: 40)
    self.view.addSubview(toolBar)
```

what I've found already:

add:

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePressed(_:)))
toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
```

but the error message says:

> Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'donePressed'

how can I change the action or how can I implement a button that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your code

```
@objc
func donePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

 }
```

Comment: the button is visible now. but how can I dismiss toolbar and picker?

Comment: make these two as a class level variables
 let picker = UIDatePicker()
 let toolBar = UIToolbar()
and in donePressed method write these lines
        self.picker.removeFromSuperview()
        self.toolBar.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: thank you very much!!! unfortunately not enough reputations to vote up..